# Spacebefore and Spaceafter for HTML in SSRS

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, reporting-services

Straightforward question-

How can I simulate the `SpaceBefore` and `SpaceAfter` properties in HTML which gets imported in SSRS?

One of our reports has quite a lengthy process it goes through:

- XML is retrieved from database,
- XML gets transformed using XSL to render HTML output,
- The html is compressed and stored into a seperate table (which we use for the reports)
- The compressed HTML is read and uncompressed in the SSRS report using custom code
- The HTML is added to a textbox which renders the output as html

SSRS is VERY limited to what can and cannot be done by HTML. My solution requires that I need to have an exact `spaceBefore` and `spaceAfter` between headings and paragraphs, so outputting `<br>` didn't comply to the requirement and `<p style="font-size:6pt">&#160;</p>` added in the XSL simply doesn't work (the `&#160;` entity is a no-break space - `&nbsp;`)

What else can I try to add exact spacing before and after paragraphs and headings?

Here is a snippet of the XSL which converts the XML to HTML and it's corresponding output (part thereof)

```
      <p style="font-size:6pt">&#160;</p>

      <!--<xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:<xsl:value-of select="$bgColor"/>;</xsl:attribute>-->
          <span>Deine Antwort: </span> 
           <xsl:call-template name="DisplayAnswer">

            <xsl:with-param name="theText" select="answer"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
```

HTML:

```
<p style="font-size:6pt"> </p>
  <span>Deine Antwort: </span>
  <ul style="margin-left:15px">
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I used for my problem.

First, I used the approach of `<p style="font-size:6pt">&#160;</p>`. I replaced the `p-tags` with `div` and added `padding-top:<required size in pt>pt`

```
          <div style="font-size:1pt;padding-top:5pt;">&#160;</div>

      <!--<xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:<xsl:value-of select="$bgColor"/>;</xsl:attribute>-->
          <span>Deine Antwort: </span> 
           <xsl:call-template name="DisplayAnswer">

            <xsl:with-param name="theText" select="answer"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
```

this created the same amount of "spacing" I required between paragraphs. I also modified this snippet where necessary between headers (which required 11pt by me) and the report rendered the HTML with the appropriate "`spacebefore`" and "`spaceafter`"

[image: correct spacing]